# Is there a recommended setup for recording an MP4 format video in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have this options for recording MP4 format and used `MPEG_4` as output format and `MPEG_4_SP` as video encoding. It is currently working but I would like to know if encoding can be improved.

I can't seem to find a relative resource for recommended setup.:

```
mVideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mVideoRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mVideoRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mVideoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);

//anything higher than frame rate 20 results to black screen
mVideoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20); 
mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
mVideoRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);

// sampling rate for AMR_WB
mVideoRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000); 

// allowed recording duration is 30 secs only... around 6mb file
mVideoRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a bunch of trial and error, this is what worked for android and when transferred to iphone.

```
        mVideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mVideoRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(441000);
        mVideoRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); // allowed recording is 30 seconds only
        mVideoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFile(uniqueOutFile);
        mVideoRecorder.prepare();
        mVideoRecorder.start();
```

Note: I use VLC for android `Information` to study MP4 files working on both Android and iPhone and try to generate the same setup.